# Диалекты русского языка

Tags: наречия, диалекты

Как известно, русский язык составляют три крупных наречия: великорусское, малорусское и белорусское. При этом в каждом из них выделяют множество всяких диалектов, говоров и т. п., которые образуют в общем рассмотрении довольно сложную систему, элементы которой не всегда можно определить однозначно. Хотелось бы уточнить у знатоков филологии, как правильнее употреблять данную терминологию (наречие, диалект, говор и др.) по отношению к русскому языку (например, на что подразделяется великорусское наречие?).

Answer (score 2):

Боюсь, что внятных рекомендаций, что чем надо называть, вы не найдёте. В отношении русского языка и его ближайших родственников руководствуются более историческими казусами нежели четкими правилами.. Но тут мне добавить нечего.

А вот что касается систематики и самих терминов... Четких критериев нет. Более того, я даже не уверен, включает ли наречие диалект или наоборот. Вполне, что это стномимы в рамках рассматриваемой классифмкации. Хотя вообще-то наречие это синоним языку.

Я, пожалуй ограничусь тремя сткпенями язык-диалект-говор.
Предложенные Ols'ой критерии мне совершенно не нравятся. Хотя бы потому, что понятия эти никак не огрнаничены "во времени и пространстве" и сводить различия к современным реалиям (государство, стандарт) и т.д. как-то не смотрится.

Более или менее стройная система получается при следующей схеме.
~ 1. Язык. Определяется общностью грамматики и словарным запасом. Отдельные специфические слова и (реже) осоьбенности в грамматике, используемые группой носителей (профессиональные, региональные и т.д.) не воспринимаются остальными как слова и конструкции чужого языка. Более серьёзнве изменения в грамматике, приводящие к непониманию фразы в целом, позволяет говорить уже о разных языках. Например: немецкий и идиш.

~ 2. Диалект. При общности грамматических конструкций наблюдаются существенные ращличия в частоте их использования, не связанные напрямую с культурой и бытом носителей. Фонетика отличается способом произношения (а не только особенностями произношения отдельных слов), расходится темп и интонация, многие слова имеют разные значения. Например: британский, американский и австралийский диалекты английского.

~ 3. Говор. Основные различия - фонетические, отдельные специфическме слова связаны главным образом с культурной средой и бытом. Как правило имеют место плавный переход с многочисленными говорами и поддиалектпми. Например: московский и петербурский говоры.

Копирайты - мои. Эта схема родилась по итогам многолетнего обсуждения подобнвых вопросов на разных форумах, особенно - на грамоте.

Answer (score 1):

Первая ваша фраза весьма архаична (времен Российской империи), поскольку сейчас ни великорусского, ни малорусского, ни белорусского наречия нет. Это **отдельные самостоятельные** языки: русский, украинский, белорусский. Они возникли из единого в прошлом общевосточнославянского языка, языка древнерусской народности, которая существовала в X — XIII вв. Поэтому долгое время по традиции в название всех трех языков входило определение «русский»: великорусский, малорусский, белорусский. Распадение древнерусского языка на три родственных объясняется исторически и лингвистически — разнонаправленным изменением некогда общей языковой системы в условиях государственной самостоятельности и феодальной разобщенности.

Диалекты **русского** языка — территориальные разновидности **русского** языка, объединяемые в традициях русской диалектологии в две основные крупные диалектные величины — **наречия** (северное и южное), между которыми расположена область переходных **говоров** (среднерусские говоры). Наречия и переходные говоры включают в свой состав группы говоров (реже выделяются подгруппы говоров). Территория среднерусских говоров — Псковская, Тверская, Московская, Владимирская, Ивановская, Нижегородская области. Севернее этого пояса — зона северного наречия, южнее — соответственно, южного.

Термины, о которых вы спрашиваете, выстраиваются в цепочку: "язык — наречие — диалект — говор" от более широкого по охвату понятия к более узкому. С одной стороны диалекты могут объединяться в наречия или группы диалектов, а с другой — делиться на говоры.

Разновидность языка может считаться диалектом, например, если:

- он не является стандартизованным литературным языком;
- его носители не имеют собственного государства или автономного образования;
- он не является престижной формой общения.

Answer (score 0):

В сравнительном языкознании принята следующая линейка терминов: язык - диалект - наречие - говор. Я подчеркиваю, что, в отличие от [[[[@olsa](/users/246/olsa)](/users/246/olsa)](/users/246/olsa)](/users/246/olsa), речь идет не только о русском языке, а о языках в целом. В русском есть своя особенность - исторически "наречие" обозначало и диалект, и целый язык, например, как Вы правильно сказали, украинский или белорусский. Самой тонкой является грань между язык-диалект, потому что в ряде случаев это определяется по политическим или культурным установкам. Возьмем, арабские диалекты. Например, определение диалекта от [[[[@olsa](/users/246/olsa)](/users/246/olsa)](/users/246/olsa)](/users/246/olsa) "•его носители не имеют собственного государства или автономного образования" тут полностью не работает. Все основные арабские диалекты имеют четкое либо государственное, либо автономное образование. Каждое арабское государство имеет свой основной диалект, и, по существу, эти "диалекты", с точки зрения лингвистики, однозначно являются самостоятельными языками. Однако! Сугубо по культурно-политическим соображениям арабы намерено называют их диалектами. Это обусловлено их коренным стремлением сохранить арабский литературный язык, язык Корана, в качестве живого и единого языка. Поэтому получается следующая картина. Устные языки, на которых они говорят, развиваются самостоятельно. Но все арабские государства тщательно следят за чистотой арабского литературного языка, развивают его, создают новые слова-неологизмы взамен американизмам (которые, кстати, затопили русский язык). В арабском языке нет почти ни одного англо-американизма, а все заимствования за тысячу с лишним лет можно пересчитать на пальцах двух рук. В то же время арабские "диалекты" отличаются друг от друга несравненно больше не только, чем американский, канадский, австралийский и др., но больше, чем русский и, например, словенский или другой самый отдаленный от русского славянский язык. Арабы совершенно не понимают, например марокканский и другие западные диалекты. Более того, они даже не понимают, что разговаривающий говорит на одном из арабских диалектов, а могут подумать, что он говорит на турецком, русском или другом каком угодно языке. Различия не только в фонетике, но и, главное, в лексике и грамматике. Например, глаголы спрягаются по собственным парадигмам. Если говорить совсем просто, то ключевая и очевидная разница между языком и диалектом состоит в следующем. Если представители разных наречий хоть как-то ПОНИМАЮТ друг друга, то это диалекты, но, если они уже НЕ ПОНИМАЮТ друг друга, и требуется переводчик, то это уже разные языки.